# Token button missing from CKEditor 5 bar

Tags: tokens, input-formats

I've recently started using CKEditor 5 on a new site.
I've enabled the Token and Token Filter modules, and checked the box on my Full Text format config screen to select 'Replaces global and entity tokens with their values'.

The editor does in fact respect tokens, but there's no button to insert one or select from the available ones, as there was in CKE4. (I had to go find the one I wanted from /admin/help/token)
Does anyone know how to enable the Token button on the CKEditor 5 button bar?

Comment: Help with developing and testing this feature: https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/3334784 and also https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter/issues/3262052

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request for a contributed module and needs to be discussed in the module's issue queue on drupal.org